# My Vue Hello World example shows double brackets and not rendered text

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to learn Vue. I started with a simple hello world example from alligator.io

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World in Vue.js</title>
  </meta>

  <body>

    <div id="hello-world-app">
      <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    </div>

    <script
      src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: "#hello-world-app",
        data() {
          return {
            msg: "Hello World!"
          }
        }
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I had also tried doing it with my own document from the offical Vue documentation Hello World. The result is the same. My page shows {{ msg }} and not Hello World. In console, it reads that Vue is not defined.

DEMO:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#hello-world-app",
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Hello World!"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="hello-world-app">
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: After your <html> open Tag you use <meta></meta> instead of <head></head>, so you're html is invalid

Comment: if Vue is not defined ... it is the reason because it is showing {{ }}  ... have you imported correctly vue path ?

Comment: Before I was viewing just as a local file in my browser. Vue didn't load that way. When I use Apache to serve the file, it does work.

Comment: Seems to work fine in jsFiddle and also here using snippets. Code updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the vue.min.js url to https, try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World in Vue.js</title>
  </meta>

  <body>

    <div id="hello-world-app">
      <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.min.js">
    </script>

    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: "#hello-world-app",
        data() {
          return {
            msg: "Hello World!"
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: That worked. I am not sure why it was in the tutorial that way other than the fact it did work when the file was served by Apache.

Comment: @Charles Dake, you can try this, it will work for you, just a simple url change.

Comment: This answer does not even explain the issue. If you accept "just copy paste this and it will work!"-answers at least consider adding some relevant information.

Comment: Also the HTML is not even correct as there are `<meta>`-tags instead `<head>` ...

Comment: @Num Lock, this code snippet was taken from alligator.io, and the problem was to identify why same snippet was printing {{ msg }} not the correct value, it is not about what is wrong or right in the existing code snippet, that is why I have not given the full explanation and just highlighted the problem and fixed the existing code snippet.

Comment: @MOnkey https://stackoverflow.com/tour I recommend a read through the tour.

Comment: "[...] we're working together to build a library of **detailed answers** [...]"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your URL shortcut. You just open your html-file locally as you stated in the comments.

Replace

`//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.min.js`

with

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.min.js`

and it will work. Also replace that `<meta>...</meta>` with `<head>...</head>`, just to make your HTML correct.

The problem is - as I already stated - that you open the file local, in which case your browser will assume `file:` and not `https:`.

Of course `file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.6/vue.min.js` most likely won't lead anywhere.

I copy-pasted your example and with this change only it was working as expected. You could have easily spotted that problem by inspecting your browser's developer tools.

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550038/is-it-valid-to-replace-http-with-in-a-script-src-http) for a related answer.